# is alkyl halide turning into alkene reduction or oxidation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

Is the reaction of 2-iodobutane turning into but-2-ene reduction or oxidation reaction?

Answer (score 1):

HI is being removed in the reaction. It is $\beta$-elimination. I really am not able to see any changes in the oxidation numbers also.

$\ce{CH3-CH(I)-CH2-CH3}$ will undergo dehydrohalogenation.

Only rearrangement in molecular structure takes place.

Comment: Why was my answer unaccepted? Like it was accepted long ago and now all of a sudden its unaccepted

Comment: I guess only OP knows why. Well, a reason could be that *technically* ox states do change, even if sum stays the same. BTW did you check out the site chat? For example [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74807/jee-chemistry-club) or the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)